# Distinct on only one column - only display FIRST duplicate row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using an SQL query in PHP to display 5 columns from my "users" table. Here is my code for that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT account_id, full_name, email, login, phone, updated_at, last_request_at, unconfirmed_email FROM $table WHERE id < '300'
```

Basically, this table has 2 types of user - admin accounts and what we'll call "subusers" - they're still users but they don't have admin privileges, and they were created by their parent admin accounts. Because of this, the parent admin account and its subusers all share the same "account_id" Here's an example (sorry it's rubbish):

```
| account_id | full_name   | Superhero?  |
| 1          | Batman      |  1          |
| 1          | Robin       |  1          |
| 1          | Magneto     |  0          |
| 2          | Spiderman   |  1          |
| 2          | The Hulk    |  1          |
| 2          | Wolverine   |  1          |
| 3          | Professor X |  1          |
| 4          | Cyclops     |  1          |
| 4          | Shrek       |  0          |
| 4          | Superman    |  1          |
| 4          | Bob         |  0          |
```

So you can pretend that Spiderman made The Hulk's and Wolverine's accounts. This tells me that Spiderman has an admin account because he's the first instance of the account_id "2".

So as you can see, while full_name is unique, there are many duplicate account_id's, I would like to refine it so that that it only displays the **first instance** of each ID - there are only 4 different account_id's so it should only show 4 entries, like so:

```
| account_id | full_name   | Superhero?  |
| 1          | Batman      |  1          |
| 2          | Spiderman   |  1          |
| 3          | Professor X |  1          |
| 4          | Cyclops     |  1          |
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why does magneto isn't a superhero while professor X is? I find that insulting :/ Seriously though, you'd be better off with another column specifiying if it's admin or not rather than some ordering gimmick.

Comment: Or even better, normalize your database with a table containing the users (both admin and subusers, with an appropriate flag) and the id of their parent, and another table with the superheroes and the user_id (not the account id!) of the new table.

Comment: I knew someone was going to pick up on that.. Magneto is a super villain! Unfortunately it's not my database, I've just been assigned with the task of showing all admin accounts in one convenient place so they can be easily contacted. There are users signing up everyday and I don't have access to the scripts which enter users into this table, so creating a NEW table would get quickly outdated. On normalising the database, I would be all in favour of that, if it makes it easier to navigate. But again... Not my database.

Comment: then you should tell your client that their database suck and they're relying on a glass sheet. Fix the database first, or run away as fast as you can.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably add another column. Now it is possible to get distinct record for every account_id using `GROUP BY` clause but results of all nonagreggated columns can be ambigius. You have to have some order you approve or indicator inside group to determine which record for every accout_id is "first". With column marking which record in each group is first query is simple. Without it you have to accept some order telling query which record is "first". On example alphabetical order of full_name:

```
SELECT account_id, 
       full_name, 
       email, 
       login, 
       phone, 
       updated_at, 
       last_request_at, 
       unconfirmed_email 
  FROM table1 WHERE full_name IN (
    SELECT MIN(full_name) 
      FROM table1 
      GROUP BY account_id 
      WHERE id < '300'
  )
```

Comment: This will not work in all the scenarios right? If an admin comes last in alphabetical order then it will pick wrong right?

Comment: Query works only in scenario than chosen order is accepted. The guy is searching for only first row in each group. First means - order have to be determined. If there is no column which can determine the order some new column determining it or just an indicator of first record should be added.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
select * from table1
group by account_id
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bfc1/3)

this will give you the first of every account_id

Comment: Group by has an implicit order?Isn't arbitrary?

Comment: Oh my god this answer is so naive... -1

Comment: I dont understand how does this work. Here you are selecting all the columns at the same time you are grouping them by account_id. Basically it's not possible right?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution to what you asked for,

```
SELECT account_id,full_name,Superhero
FROM(
SELECT p.*,( 
            CASE account_id 
            WHEN @curType 
            THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
            ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := account_id END
          ) + 1 AS rank
FROM      test p, (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '', @curRank := 0) r) A
WHERE rank=2;
```

[**Sql_Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b9ab/1)

## Output:

```
ACCOUNT_ID  FULL_NAME   SUPERHERO
1             Batman    1
2            Spiderman  1
3           Professor X 1
4            Cyclops    1
```